# Game screen management

Tags: c++, game-engine

I am working on a screen manager for a miniature game engine, and so far I cannot find a proper solution to managing screen objects without using the 'blob' for each one of the screens. Is blob tolerable in such circumstances where I need a list of renderable objects in one controller?

Comment: Blob? Forgive me, but what do you mean by blob?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object

Comment: Each screen would have to be made out of the different needed resource management components, so in your case, each screen could have a renderable object manager object which encapsulates and manages all of the renderables, does frustrum culling etc.. I dont quite understand what answer you are looking for this, do you want a structure for your screen and management or do you want to know whether you can ca have it managed or not?

Comment: The question is: since blob is generally avoided anti-pattern, would this be a bad idea or a proper approach to a screen manager? Is there a better way to manage things on screen or the blob is acceptable or neccessary?

Comment: Ok I understand, to say whether your implementation is inadequate you first need to explain and present some examples of your code and structure, 'blob' on its own does not explain how you have structured as the God_object wiki page you linked also mentions a lack of any kind of subroutines. Now your structure I am sure will have some degree of abstraction without knowing this it is hard to comment on it.

Comment: Well currently I haven't really started developing it thoroughly (no code at the given time), but for now, I was going to make a list of -all- the elements on the screen, and send them to a bare render command just for showing each one of them. Would that actually be a bad approach or not? Question was just asked in general, what would you advise me to do, if you were to start coding such a piece of code - what approach would you go for if there's any other possibly more potent than this one. I was hoping for a pattern or something commonly used by coders, since I haven't yet seen such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider using the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) in this situation. Otherwise, if you're not careful, it's very easy to end up with a bunch of spaghetti code where the screen code is reaching into the game code, and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I have been asking for so far. I've totally forgotten about the pattern, but seems like I have somehow subliminally managed to imbue it into the code. Thanks for giving me directions, that's all I've wanted!

Answer (score 1):

I have recently coded something you might call a "screen manager".

I started with the idea that, whatever game I make, the render system is going to be pretty much the same in terms of how to render (how to manage the hardware). The thing that changes is what is rendered, and how to draw it (do I want a box or a circle or a bitmap.. representing what... etc).

So basically the "game state" is responsible for knowing how to render itself, and should do so when given a render surface from the screen manager or graphics system (It should also be responsible for other things like knowing how input, physics, etc act upon itself).

I implemented it with a singleton for the GraphicsSystem object, which was called something like this:

```
GameState gs;
Graphics::System().Init(DOUBLE_BUFFER, 640, 480);
...
while(still_looping) {
    ...
    // When it is time to render:
    Graphics::System().RenderGameState(&gs);
}
```

And how, you ask, does the Graphics::System() singleton know how to render the game state? It knows because the game state is inherited from a listener exposed by the graphics system...

```
//within GraphicsSystem.h...
class BaseRenderer
{
public:
    virtual void Render(BITMAP *render_surface) = 0;
};

//GameState defined with:
class GameState : public BaseRenderer
{
public:
    void Render(BITMAP *render_surface);
    ...
```

You can do this with nearly all the subsystems... (probably not timing, as it is needed in the game loop).

Why singletons? Well, it is C++ and I'm assuming there is only 1 screen, or graphics subsystem to render with. I'm not sure if you are using multiple screens, or a mobile phone or a console. The other way I would do it is to have the graphics system as static global variables in a separate file, giving them file scope only, and having accessor functions in that file (my old C way of doing things).

The key though is encapsulation. Let your screen manager manage the hardware. Let your game state dictate how itself should be expressed.

If this misses the point, please clear up your question and I can edit the answer.

Comment: Your answer is interesting, though I do have my code set up (and working by this point), I just tried to get an idea is that a good idea or not, and if not how would you manage the objects currently being rendered. For example what Mike said would be the answer to my question.